# How to config queueSize and ThreadPoolSize when using Apache Phoenix JDBC driver?

Tags: java, scala, jdbc, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am using Apache Phoenix JDBC driver and recently I encountered such issue:

```
Task org.apache.phoenix.job.JobManager$InstrumentedJobFutureTask@21a34e8c[Not completed, task = org.apache.phoenix.iterate.ParallelIterators$1@2d618b69] rejected from org.apache.phoenix.job.JobManager$1@c17227f[Running, pool size = 128, active threads = 128, queued tasks = 4995, completed tasks = 7866]
```

After googled I learned I should change the `phoenix.query.queueSize` and `phoenix.query.threadPoolSize` in `hbase-site.xml`. But for JDBC driver, do I still need to config these configurations in the XML file? If so, where should I put the file?

I have tried put these two items in JDBC connection properties but doesn't work:

```scala
val properties: Properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("phoenix.query.threadPoolSize", "1024")
properties.setProperty("phoenix.query.queueSize", "50000")

DriverManager.getConnection(uri, properties)
```

So I guess these two configurations are setup configurations instead of connection properties?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by reading Phoenix code:
[1](https://github.com/apache/phoenix/blob/934d3a3d281702996e63333cecf5031bb103c9f4/phoenix-core/src/main/java/org/apache/phoenix/query/QueryServicesOptions.java#L413)
[2](https://github.com/apache/phoenix/blob/6195f8e7b5efeecd5c736ba0ef121b706c875d8d/phoenix-core/src/main/java/org/apache/phoenix/query/ConfigurationFactory.java#L49)
[3](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/hbase-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration.java#L80)

So in one word, put the hbase-site.xml file into the `src/main/resources` path and the Phoenix will read the configuration.